# Probability qual problem about Polya's criterion (I guess)

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $\mu$ is non negative, $\sigma$-finite measure on $(0,\infty)$ so that
$$c:=\int_0^\infty x\mu (dx)\in(0,\infty)$$
Let 
$$\phi(u):=\exp\left(\int(e^{iux}-1)\mu (dx)\right)$$

Prove that there is a random variable T such that $Ee^{iuT}=\phi(u)$ for all real u, and also prove that $ET=c$. Here $"i"$ refer for the imaginary number. Actually it says, $\phi$ is a characteristic function of some random variable T. I tried to use Polya's criterion, but it did not work,  I could not find any other theorem. Any help hints are welcome.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Poisson process $\Pi$ with intensity measure $\mu$ and $T=\sum\limits_{x\in\Pi}x$.